# How to port project treble to a device?

Tags: android, root, partition, nexus-5

I own a Nexus 5. Developers have successfully added a vendor partition to the device. I am a noob in android development can anyone tell me how can I port project treble for my Nexus 5. I know how to use Linux. I know a bit about device tree and other stuff. Can we simply move /system/vendor to vendor partition and get treble working?

Comment: It's incredibly involved. I'm not a noob to Android development or AOSP development and I have no idea how to do it. It's also an incredibly broad topic, which isn't suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just get started and come back with specific questions.